# How to create my own array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, iterator

```
a = MyArray.new(3){ |i| (i+1).to_s }
a << 1
puts " #{a.size} #{a[1]} #{a.first} "
b = MyArray.new; b.push("a").push("b")
a += b
```

and my own a.ok("foo") own variable a.nowy etc.

How to create array class with my own variables and methods and with all the methods of array:
 [] each sort .push delete ....

P.S. is posible to take in array only specyfic elements? for example only "strings" or only integers? 
redefining initialize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, but first read this: http://words.steveklabnik.com/beware-subclassing-ruby-core-classes

```
class MyClass < Array

  def my_new_method
    # do fancy array tricks here
  end

end
```

Comment: show me how I can add my variable and method to MyClass m = MyClass.new(1) p m.variable m[2]

Comment: If I create a = MyClass.new and b = MyClass.new a+=b is array. not MyClass. I lost all my variable

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance!

```
class MyClass < Array
  #implement functionality
  def initialize(args)
    super()
  end

  def custom_push(element)
    self.push(element)
  end
end
```

You can create new methods in your class, and override methods that already exist in the `Array` class.

It's worth mentioning that `each` and `sort` are not methods on the `Array` class, they are part of the `Enumerable` module that `Array` includes. It's a bit of a nitpick, but important to know.

Comment: is possible check what is pushed into array? redefine initialize?

Comment: I can put to array in many ways, << 1 init when creating .push etc. a must redefinig all to select only integer or string? I need Array to collect only String and integer

Comment: I don't understand that last comment, but what you are trying to do sounds pretty nefarious. Proceed with caution

Comment: tell me is possible to create my own Array class to storing only "String and Integer without fixnum, nil, etc?

Comment: Yes, there's a handful of different ways. I would use an observer to listen to additions on the array: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html

When the array changes, raise an exception if the type of the newly added element doesnt match what you want

Comment: why this not working?  `class Spoko < Array
     attr_reader :nowy
     def initialize(s)
      @nowy = 1
  super()
 end
end

aa = Prog.new
aa << "Miód" << "Lód" << "Rak" << "Parasol"
p aa.map { |i| i.reverse }
aa.delete_at(2)
puts "#{aa[1]} #{aa.size} #{a.nowy}"

    aa.each do |a|
     puts " #{a} [#{a.class.name}] "
    end`

Comment: add some variable to Your example

Comment: please paste your example into the question where it is easier to read